# How to check if the biometric scanner is available and initialized in Xamarin android BiometricPrompt

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, biometrics, android-9.0-pie

Failed biometric(fingerprint) scan attempts are handled by OnAuthenticationFailed() callback of BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback class.

The behavior I noticed is, it lets the user attempt 5 invalid fingerprint scans (each time the fail callback is invoked) and then the prompt dismisses. Within the next 30 secs, if we try to re-build a BiometricPrompt instance and try to authenticate, it does not show the prompt which I think is the default behavior of BiometricPrompt.

Is there anyway to check if the **biometric scanner is available and initialised** if the user attempts to re-invoke biometric prompt within the said 30secs?

How can I handle that use case?

xamarin android BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback does not have an override method "onAuthenticationError" to handle error callbacks and thus I'm unable to handle error code "BIOMETRIC_ERROR_TIMEOUT".

If someone has a solution for this, please do let me know your resolution.

Comment: Use this plugin : https://github.com/smstuebe/xamarin-fingerprint

Answer (score 1):

I believe that BiometricPrompt is not fully ported to Xamarin yet...

I'm still looking for a source that can double check this info for me, but I haven't found it either.